# With search_api_solr, how can I apply an significant field based boost when using solr 6.x?

Tags: 8, search

I am using the **solr** backend for **search_api** on a drupal 8 site.

I have added the *value* of a taxonomy term reference field (`field_promoted_search`) to the index.

If an item of content has `field_promoted_search` with value matching the search term, I would like it to get a significant boost (eg ^1000), pushing it to the top of the search results.

Adding a high 'boost' value at `admin/config/search/search-api/index/content/fields` worked as expected when the server was using solr <6, but since moving to 6.1.0, this does not work as expected. This may be because search_api_solr/solarium is using a *multiplicative* boost rather than *additive*. This is not seem as useful to me as this multiplies the relevance achieved by other fields, rather than solely privileging `field_promoted_search`, though I am uncertain of this aspect.

I have tried adding a boost *query* for this promoted search field to the solarium query using `hook_search_api_solr_query_alter`. This requires me to pass each search key as a boosted query, and the effect seem to be affected by the order of the keys (and also my result does not end up top).

```
$keys = $query->getKeys();
unset($keys['#conjunction']);
// Boost results where search term matches promoted search field.
$boost_keys = [];
$boost_value = 1000;
foreach ($keys as $key) {
  $boost_keys[] = '"' . $key . '"^' . $boost_value;
}
$solarium_query->getEDisMax()->setBoostQuery('ss_promoted_search:' . implode(' OR ', $boost_keys));
```

When I attempt to use a boost *function* instead, I get an error from back from Solr and the query does not run (I have tried several functions).

```
// Format is: "funcA(arg1,arg2)^1.2 funcB(arg3,arg4)^2.2"
$solarium_query->getEDisMax()->setBoostFunctions("ord(ss_promoted_search,1)^1000");
```

Any advice much appreciated.

---

My reference for additive vs multiplicative boost methods is this [very helpful article](https://nolanlawson.com/2012/06/02/comparing-boost-methods-in-solr/).

Comment: Related: "Because of multiplying inside recursion, HTML Filter's tag boost can produce astronomical boost values, which besides being nonsensical, breaks the Solr boost_term in Search API Solr by exceeding PHP_FLOAT_MAX" https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/3209167